# How do multiple users execute on the same code base?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, concurrency, webserver

When you publish an ASP.NET Core web application and add the folders to your application in IIS many users can access the site.

If 1,000 users logged in at the same time and all did the same thing at the same time in the application, say updated their profile, what is happening on the server?

Are all the users executing on the same code or is the source code duplicated to prevent concurrency issues?

If I were to remotely debug my app by putting a breakpoint in the UpdateProfile method would I see each user come through serially or would there be race conditions?

From experience I'm confident there will not be a race condition but I'm not sure why... I'd imagine session has something to do with it...

Comment: I also wanted to know this .@JohnOsborne

Comment: The source code doesn't really run on the server. Your code gets compiled into [IL code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) and placed into a DLL. And there's no need to duplicate any of the logic to handle multiple concurrent requests, because multiple threads can execute the same method at the same time. You do have to be careful about shared resources, such as static fields/properties (best to just not use them) or other singleton objects that might be shared across threads.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all make the distinction between "users logged in and did the same thing", which is a user experience (UX) thing they did in their browser (client side) and what happened on the server. What really happens, is they (generally speaking) all sent simultaneous (or nearly simultaneous) HttpRequests. So what the server (IIS or the like) does is issue 1000 parallel tasks (concurrently), and respond with an HttpResponse to each of these separately. There is no concurrency management. If say, they all update a counter variable (in say table GeneralConstants in the db), you would get some wacky issues. If you want to prevent such concurrency, use the lock(...) statement or something of that nature.

If your updating different things (say, as you said - each user updates his own profile), there no concurrency going on (because these are different resources), but that has little to do with the session, and more to do with that each is doing his own thing.

Comment: Suppose the counter showed 15 before they began. 1000 of them sent requests to the server. 50 of them got the counter 15, and most of them updated the counter to be 16. an error was generated (simultaneous updates to the same line in the db). Meanwhile the other 950 read the counter and got 16, and say updated it to 17. then at the end the very first request finished its update (it read 15 remember?)  and now the counter reads 16 (or 17, or 562 or whatever the last one in the race conditions wrote). like I said wacky results. :o)

Answer (score 0):

> Are all the users executing on the same code or is the source code duplicated to prevent concurrency issues?

They would execute the same code, or rather its better to say they execute the same instructions.

> If I were to remotely debug my app by putting a breakpoint in the UpdateProfile method would I see each user come through serially or would there be race conditions?

This depends on how the UpgradeProfile method is called.  Most likely it would be a "race condition" in that each request would be running on its own thread and each thread would reach and execute the UpdateProfile method as it progresses along thru the application.  Your processor performs the thread (and process) scheduling and so its very much non-deterministic....unless your application somehow makes it deterministic.

What's not clear from your question is what kind of "race condition" are you worried about?  If 1000 users are updating their own profile, how would that be affected by other users?